# Display message after logout via Silex SecurityServiceProvider

Tags: events, silex

I am using the *SecurityServiceProvider* to secure my Silex application and would like to display a message after the user has logged out by navigating to the **logout_path** route.

The message should be stored in the sessions flash bag so that my template can automatically display it after.

I have tried adding an application middleware, but where not able to hook my code in. The before hook doesn't seem to work, because it happens after security and thus after the security's redirected back to my home page.

The before hook with the **Application::EARLY_EVENT** seems to be to early because as far as I know does the Security provider destroy the session after logout.

Before I keep trying to find a sort of working but probably dirty solution I would like to ask what the best/cleanest solution for this case would be?

**UPDATE:** After npms hint for a logout event handler I found [this article](http://www.reecefowell.com/2011/10/26/redirecting-on-loginlogout-in-symfony2-using-loginhandlers/) on Google, which describes how to tackle the problem in Symfony very well.

In Silex things are slightly different though and after reading the source of the *SecurityServiceProvider* I came up with this solution.

```php
$app['security.authentication.logout_handler._proto'] = $app->protect(function ($name, $options) use ($app) {
    return $app->share(function () use ($name, $options, $app) {
        return new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler(
            $app['security.http_utils'],
            isset($options['target_url']) ? $options['target_url'] : '/'
        );
    });
});

class CustomLogoutSuccessHanler extends DefaultLogoutSuccessHandler {

    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('info', "Logout success!");
        return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, $this->targetUrl);
    }
}
```

The problem however is, that the flashbag message doesn't exist anymore after the redirect. So it seems that the session is being destroyed after the logout success handler is executed... or am I missing something? Is this even the right way to do it?

**UPDATE:** Still haven't found a proper solution yet. But this works.

I have added a parameter to the target url of the logout and use it to detect if a logout was made.

```php
$app->register( new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'pattern'=> '/user',
            'logout' => array(
                'logout_path' => '/user/logout',
                'target_url' => '/?logout'
            ),
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: there should be an event you can listen on the logout to execute a custom listener.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and your thoughts leaded me to a solution, thank you!

First define logout in the **security.firewall**:

```php
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'general' => array(
            'logout' => array(
                'logout_path' => '/admin/logout',
                'target_url' => '/goodbye'
            )
        )
    ),
));
```

Create a *CustomLogoutSuccessHandler* which handles the needed **GET** parameters for the logout, in this case **redirect**, **message** and **pid**:

```php
class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler extends DefaultLogoutSuccessHandler
{

    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        // use another target?
        $target = $request->query->get('redirect', $this->targetUrl);

        $parameter = array();
        if (null != ($pid = $request->query->get('pid'))) {
            $parameter['pid'] = $pid;
        }
        if (null != ($message = $request->query->get('message'))) {
            $parameter['message'] = $message;
        }
        $parameter_str = !empty($parameter) ? '?'.http_build_query($parameter) : '';

        return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, $target.$parameter_str);
    }
}
```

Register the handler:

```php
$app['security.authentication.logout_handler.general'] = $app->share(function () use ($app) {
    return new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler(
        $app['security.http_utils'], '/goodbye');
});
```

The trick to make this working as expected is to use another route to logout:

```php
$app->get('/logout', function() use($app) {
    $pid = $app['request']->query->get('pid');
    $message = $app['request']->query->get('message');
    $redirect = $app['request']->query->get('redirect');
    return $app->redirect(FRAMEWORK_URL."/admin/logout?pid=$pid&message=$message&redirect=$redirect");
});
```

**/logout** set the needed parameters and execute the regular logout **/admin/logout**

Now you can use

```
/logout?redirect=anywhere
```

to redirect to any other route after logout or

```
/logout?message=xyz
```

(encoded) to prompt any messages in the **/goodbye** dialog.

Comment: I like the idea to add a redirect param and I think it's well implement the way you did it. What I am not getting is the custom logout route. Couldn't you just add the parameters to the systems default logout route?

Comment: I had tried to add the parameters directly to the default logout route, but they are not passed through to the controller so it didn't work. Using another logout route enable the passing through, therefore I'm using this way.